# Advice for building a browser-based audio mixer up to 32 tracks

Tags: javascript, audio, mixing

As a personal hobby I am looking to build an online audio mixer where I can upload individual instrument tracks, control individual volumes of each track, and export the mixed down version. I've been trying (and have come pretty close) with javascript. I really would like to stay away from flash if possible, but I'm really looking for suggestions for technologies to try. If anyone has any suggestions on languages that are good at stuff like this or libraries that I am missing, please let me know!

I have a test environment that I have been using:

http://driverstestpractice.com/sandbox

Currently all tracks on the site are set to the click track in order to test the track sync (which as you can tell is a little off)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this myself, but I remember seeing [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/amazing-audio-api-javascript-demos) from Ajaxian.com.

Comment: That api is pretty cool and it looks like it is capable of doing what I need.  Only problem with it is it's only firefox :(  I really need a cross browser option.  Thanks for the input!